# Lightning dropdownlist component

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Can anyone show me what is the complete code for lightning Drop-down List.

[image]

Here is my code ..

```
    <div class="Styler">
        <ui:inputSelect label="Active Events">
           <aura:iteration items="{!v.ActiveEvents}" var="wew">
             <ui:inputSelectOption value="{!wew.Name}"/> 
           </aura:iteration>
        </ui:inputSelect>     
    </div>
```

Can Anyone help me to reach out the exact code for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean but the exact code for that. Are you looking for the aura source code behind those components? If that's the case then you can look for yourself, the aura framework is open-source. The repository is [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura).

[Here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/inputSelect) is the [`ui:inputSelect`](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/inputSelect) component. And [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/inputSelectOption) is the [`ui:inputSelectOption`](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/inputSelectOption) component.